# When does probationary period end?

Tags: united-kingdom, notice-period, probation

I am trying to understand when my probation period ends.
My contract states that

> The first 6 months is probation period and notice is 1 week for either  party and once its ended notice is 1 month.
>
> For avoidance of doubt, Probationary period is only over once the manager confirms over email its ended.

In my company there is no official confirmation usually when one's probation period ends.

I am planning to change jobs due to personal reasons and not sure if the probation period ends in the first 6 calender months or the first 6 months counted from the date of joining. (My date of joining was towards the end of April 2019)

I am currently nearing the completion of the first 6 months from the date of joining hence the question whether my notice is 1 week or a month.

Comment: Submit giving 1 week notice as you are still within the probationary period.

Answer (score 2):

Ask? The only way to be sure.

Otherwise any answers will be speculation

Comment: Yes thats one way to go about it.
I am unsure whether to ask, since it might trigger something at the company. I don't want to give them any reason to believe that I am leaving and extend my '1 week' notice to '1 month' to hamper my chances.

Answer (score 2):

"6 months" means a complete 6 month period from the date of joining. Not 6 month-names.

However, depending on how far you are in the application process, it would be prudent to tell potential employers that you need a full month of notice. Remember that there is usually a gap between handing in your application and being invited to interview, another gap between being invited and attending the interview, and often a third gap between the interview and you actually being given an offer. If, during this time, you go past the 6 months probation then you will look rather silly when you have to explain that actually you need more notice now.

In the UK it is very normal to have to give at least one month of notice.

Comment: 6 months from date of joining means 30 day calender month or 31 day? What i am trying to figure out is if joined on 25th April, does that mean the probation period is till 25 October or should i reduce days?

Comment: That will depend on your company and their interpretation of "1 month". Usually you would equate 25th of April with 25th of October and ignore the fact that months are different lengths...... but even if you did know exactly my advice would be not to try and game the situation down to the exact day. Lawyering your notice period like that is likely to cause bad feeling for a very trivial gain.

Comment: Being cautious (giving 1 month notice) is definitely the best solution. It's possible that the company will notify you of the end of your probation period before the official 6 months is up (I've heard of this happening). Accepting any notification, whether verbal or written, and whether official or unofficial, that your position is permanent or probation is over could be taken as confirmation that you will give 1 month's notification thereafter.